# Array element count in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an array like

```
[
   {date:'1/8/14',code:'AV-502'},
   {date:'1/8/14',code:'AV-501'},
   {date:'2/8/14',code:'AV-502'},
   {date:'2/8/14',code:'AV-501'},
   {date:'2/8/14',code:'AV-502'}
]
```

How can I get the count of each code for a date ie count of `AV-502` for  date `1/8/14`
and the same for `2/8/14` and so on in jquery.
The result needed is like

```
[
       {date:'1/8/14',code:'AV-502',count:2},
       {date:'1/8/14',code:'AV-501',count:3},
       {date:'2/8/14',code:'AV-501',count:5}
]
```

Comment: also give the expected outputs too

Comment: You've said you want the count, but your "the result needed" is an array. Which is it?

Comment: Thats not a valid JS object. 1/8/14, etc. should be string no?

Comment: this is not valid json array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var getCount = function (date, code) {
    var count = 0;
    $.each(arr, function (key, val) {
        if (val.date === date && val.code === code) {
            count++;
        }
    });
    return count;
}

//call this function
getCount('1/8/14', 'AV-502');
```

Answer (score 1):

You loop through and count them.

You have a bunch of options for *how* you loop through and count them. [Several are described in this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript).

In addition to those, there's the ES5 `Array#reduce` function:

```
var count = yourArray.reduce(function(prev, entry) {
    return entry.code === "AV-502" ? prev + 1 : prev;
}, 0);
```